# Why my Switch Statement is returning Undefined . As it should be behaving like this? Weird JS

Tags: javascript, recursion, switch-statement

```
function reccursion(){
    let random=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
    if(squares[random]==null){
// Here I'm getting the random between 0-8 range in console but in switch statement sometimes returning undefined
      console.log(random,'random value generated') 
      switch(random){
        case 0:
          return 0
        case 1:
          return 1
        case 2:
          return 2
        case 3:
          return 3
        case 4:
          return 4
        case 5:
          return 5
        case 6:
          return 6
        case 7:
          return 7
        case 8:
          return 8
      }
    }else{
      reccursion();
    }
}
```

Here I have created the recursive function where if any value of an square'( Array of length 9 and index is 0-8 )'  which is selected randomly is null so I should return its index no which is random value. But some times it is giving me undefine even after there is null value present in the square

Comment: The `else` block doesn't `return` anything...

Comment: You should do `else { return reccursion(); }` - and also, *recursion* has one `c`. Finally, instead of the complicated `switch` I'd say you can do just `return random;`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the return statement in the else branch :

Try this code and it should never return undefined.

```
function reccursion(){
    let random=Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
    if(squares[random]==null){
// Here I'm getting the random between 0-8 range in console but in switch statement sometimes returning undefined
      console.log(random,'random value generated') 
      switch(random){
        case 0:
          return 0
        case 1:
          return 1
        case 2:
          return 2
        case 3:
          return 3
        case 4:
          return 4
        case 5:
          return 5
        case 6:
          return 6
        case 7:
          return 7
        case 8:
          return 8
      }
    }else{
      return reccursion();
    }
}
```